# Вычленить из html текст с заголовками

Tags: python

Помогите собрать в массив данные из полученного куска html кода.
Нужны время и текстовые заголовки новостей.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = requests.get("https://www.bfm.ru")
print(response.status_code)
soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')
news = soup.select(".overview")
print(news)
```

Сейчас получилось только весь блок целиком записать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения которые вы ищите, можно получить следующим способом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = requests.get("https://www.bfm.ru")
print(response.status_code)
soup = BS(response.text,  "lxml")
news = soup.select(".overview")
for n in news:
    n = n.find_all('li')
    for i in n:
        print(i.text)
```

Результат:

```
10:18  Глава Госдепа начал свой первый визит в Среднюю Азию с Казахстана  
09:51  Лукашенко заявил об уникальном для Украины моменте для прекращения конфликта  
09:19  Часть Евпатории осталась без воды  
08:51  В Новосибирске несколько полицейских уволены за взятки  
08:19  В Минобороны предсказывают провокацию с химоружием на Украине  
07:50  В Туапсе произошел пожар на нефтебазе  
07:22  Крупная автоавария произошла в московском тоннеле  
07:15  Служба федеральных маршалов США подверглась хакерской атаке  
06:46  Посол РФ в Вашингтоне Антонов обвинил США в существенных нарушениях центральных положений ДСНВ  
06:15  Bloomberg: Илон Маск вернул себе звание самого богатого человека в мире  
05:44  Япония запретит экспорт в Россию «укрепляющих промышленность» товаров  
04:50  Япония ввела санкции против замминистра обороны РФ Горемыкина и главы концерна «Калашников» Лушникова  
03:35  Месси стал лучшим футболистом года по версии ФИФА 
.......
```